# Fundamental group of a smooth closed 3-manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, fundamental-groups

I wanna find an example of a smooth, without boundary, 3-manifold M, such that $\pi_1(M)$ have non trivial torsion, and M can be smoothly embedded in $R^4$.
Any ideas?

Comment: The boundaries of Mazur manifolds smoothly embed in $S^4$ and are homology spheres, so have finite fundamental group. The fundamental groups are in general nontrivial. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur_manifold

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Wikipedia says "a Mazur manifold is a contractible,...", so I don't think the fundamental group is in general nontrivial.

Comment: @Thorgott the boundary is not contractible.

Comment: Sorry I messed up on two points! Trivial homology doesn't mean finite fundamental group and the boundaries of Mazur manifolds are topologically embeddable but not smoothly embeddable. I am not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score 7):

You can find a very detailed discussion of the problem of **smooth** embeddability of compact 3-manifold in $R^4$ in

*Budney, Ryan; Burton, Benjamin A.*, Embeddings of 3-manifolds in $S^4$ from the point of view of the 11-tetrahedron census,  [ZBL07589799](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:07589799).

(A free arXiv version is [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.2346.pdf).)

Of interest to you:

(a) The manifold $S^3/Q_8$ (where $Q_8$ is the "quaternion group" embedded in $S^3$ as a subgroup of unit quaternions) embeds in $R^4$: Take any smooth embedding $RP^2\to R^4$.  Then take the boundary of a tubular neighborhood of the image. It will be diffeomorphic to $S^3/Q_8$. The manifold $S^3/Q_8$ has fundamental group of order 8.

(b) For any coprime integers $p, q$, with $p$ odd, the connected sum of the lens spaces  $L_{p,q} \# (- L_{p,q})$ embeds smoothly in $R^4$. The fundamental group of this manifold is infinite but contains elements of order $p$. The "minus" sign means "opposite orientation."

See the discussion following Theorem 2.15 in the paper.