# What are the orientable prime compact three-manifolds that can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

I am a physicist working in quantum field theory and it happens that I stumble on the problem of the title: What are the orientable compact prime three-manifolds that can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$. My starting point is an orientable compact three-manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$ that I can decompose in connected sums. I am intuitibly assuming that this decomposition can be done inside $\mathbb{R}^4$and that the resulting prime manifolds are also embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$. Any information on the higher dimensional problem, that is, prime n-manifolds embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ would also be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know, but MathOverflow says it's very hard and the complete answer isn't known https://mathoverflow.net/questions/232407/which-closed-3-manifolds-can-be-embedded-in-r4. 

(I don't think the prime assumption reduces the complexity of the problem -- if you can embed $M$ and $N$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then you can embed their connected sum in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Comment: That MO question is not restricted to prime manifolds though.

Comment: All 3-dimensional homology spheres embed topologically in $\mathbb R^4$ but, likely, this is not what you care about. For smooth embeddings, the problem is wide-open.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, regarding connected sums, it is much more subtle than you think. On one hand, if $M_1, M_2$ are 3-dimensional manifolds each of which embeds in $\mathbb R^4$, then their connected sum also embeds. But the converse is false.  For instance, lens spaces $L(p,q), p>1$, do not embed smoothly in $\mathbb R^4$, while for any coprime integers $p, q$, with $p$ odd, the connected sum of the lens spaces  $L_{p,q} \# (- L_{p,q})$ embeds smoothly in $\mathbb R^4$. (Here the negative sign means the opposite orientation.) See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4618336/fundamental-group-of-a-smooth-closed-3-manifold/4618439#4618439) and reference  therein, as well as

*Donald, Andrew*, [**Embedding Seifert manifolds in $S^{4}$**](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-2014-06174-6), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 367, No. 1, 559-595 (2015). [ZBL1419.57046](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1419.57046).

All in all, the problem of smooth embeddings of closed 3-manifolds in $\mathbb R^4$ is wide-open. It is Problem 3.20 on Kirby's famous list of problems in 3-dimensional topology. Even in the case of **Seifert manifolds**, which is arguably, the nicest class of 3-dimensional manifolds, only partial answers are known. (And, with one exceptions, all Seifert manifolds are prime.)